# Masonry target last item in each column

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-masonry, masonry

Is there a way to give each item that sits at the bottom of a masonry column a class to allow targeting with CSS?

The number of columns changes with page width so the items that are at the bottom of the column will change and the page increases or decreases in size.

To illustrate the problem I want to remove the border bottom from each item that sits at the bottom of a column in the 2 images below:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `layoutComplete` callback to loop over the objects and give each item at the bottom a class of last by inspecting the value of their top property:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var $container = $('.masonry');

    $container
        .masonry({
          itemSelector: 'article'
        })
        .masonry( 'on', 'layoutComplete', function( msnryInstance, laidOutItems ) {
            styleMasonry();
        });

    styleMasonry(); 

    function styleMasonry() {
        var cols = {};
        var top, left;
        $('.masonry > *').each(function(){
            $(this).removeClass('last');
            top = parseInt($(this).css('top').replace('px', ''));
            left = $(this).css('left');
            if(typeof cols[left] == 'undefined') {
                cols[left] = {top: top, object: $(this)};
            } else if(top > cols[left].top) {
                cols[left] = {top: top, object: $(this)};
            }
        });
        $.each(cols, function( index, item ) {
            item.object.addClass('last');
        });
    }

});
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to find out the css for your item and need to update it.
if your item is `<div class="item"> .....</div>` then into your item class into css you have to replace bottom-bottom part.

```
.item{
border-bottom:none;  // or border-bottom: 0px;
}
```

may be this is helpful to you.

Comment: Ok, so lets go with each element has a class of item. The CSS in your answer would remove the border bottom from ALL items, not just the ones at the bottom of the column. There is no class that exists for items at the bottom of the column so will need to write some javascript to add an a class to the items at the bottom of the column. That's what I'm asking if anyone knows how to do.

Comment: Ok so you want to remove bottom border of only ones which it at bottom. Can you please update your image to highlight that border you want to delete?

Comment: Well, the ones at the bottom of the columns... Thanks for taking a look but I've figured out a solution anyway.